# How to maintain paging on the bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, tabs

I have 4 tabs in my index. Each contains a table with details about products in my database. I added a pagination underneath the table, but when I try to use tab paging, it always returns in the first tab. I tried to use Laravel's appends, but I still have the same problem.

**My list tabs**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Loja</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#mlb" aria-controls="mlb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Mercado Livre</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#cnova" aria-controls="cnova" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CNova</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#b2w" aria-controls="b2w" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">B2W</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#walmart" aria-controls="walmart" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Wal-Mart</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Content of tabs**
(I've just put the tabs that I'm currently using)

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    <div id="product-table">
        @include('admin.product-table')
    </div>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="mlb">
    @include('admin.product-mlb')
</div>
```

Any suggestion? 
I have seen some articles related to this, but I still have difficulties.

Comment: Try this way. may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498408/php-pagination-bootstrap-nav-tabs-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the way could be appending query string to the pagination object like

```
$users->appends(['page' => 'home'])->links();
```

and in your view cross checking for that query string as

```
<li role="presentation" @if (Request::query('page') === null || Request::query('page') == 'home') class="active" @endif>
    <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Loja</a>
</li>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane @if (Request::query('page') === null || Request::query('page') == 'home') active @endif" id="home">
    <div id="product-table">
        @include('admin.product-table')
    </div>
</div>
```